# Why aren't cyclic lists considered lists in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, circular-list, cycle-detection

I haven't found any questions regarding this for the Scheme programming language, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

While doing some dabbling in the interpreter I encountered a peculiar occurrence:

```lisp
(define li (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e))

(list? li)
;; -> #t

(set-cdr! (cddddr li) li) ;; list is now circular

(list? li)
;; -> #f
```

Apparently, upon changing the list object to now be cyclic, `list?` will return `#f`.

How come Scheme doesn't consider a cyclic list to be a list? I guess it has something to do with the formal definition of list, but how does Scheme formulate such definition? Also, how is `list?` even implemented in terms of possessing the property of detecting a cyclic list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a natural definition of a list is that a list is either:

- the empty list, `()`;
- or a pair whose car is any object and whose cdr is a list.

Note that a circular list does not meet this criteria, and neither does something like `(x . y)` or `(x y . z)`.

I believe that this is the definition of 'list' used by R<sup>n</sup>RS for at least some values of n (in particular it's the definition used by [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)).  R5RS is clear, again, that `list?` must return false for a circular list (so in particular it must have an occurs check or something like it).

Other Lisps have historically been much more lax about this: Common Lisp for instance defines it's `listp` simply checks if an object is either `()` or a cons, and defines lists as being elements of that type.  What Scheme calls 'lists' Common Lisp calls 'proper lists'.

Here is a version of `list?` which uses an a tortoise-and-hare algorithm to check for circularity (this may not be correct and I think is overcomplex even if it is, but it's late):

```
(define (lyst? l)
  (cond
    [(null? l)
     #t]
    [(not (cons? l))
     #f]
    [else
     (let lyst-loop? ([tortoise l]
                      [hare (cdr l)])
       (cond [(eq? hare tortoise)
              #f]
             [(null? hare)
              #t]
             [(cons? hare)
              (cond [(null? (cdr hare))
                     #t]
                    [(not (cons? (cdr hare)))
                     #f]
                    [else
                     (lyst-loop? (cdr tortoise)
                                 (cdr (cdr hare)))])]
             [else
              #f]))]))
```

Comment: Ah, it's naturally defined. I see you. Is this definition formally stated somewhere by the Scheme-team?  Also: do you know whether its possible to see the source code implementation of procedures that are in the standard library such as `list?`-procedure? Im using DrRacket.

Comment: R5RS states pretty much this, I have not checked other versions of the standard.  I'm sure the Racket sources are available, yes.

Comment: Also a `list?` can be made without mutation of any kind, while a cyclic list cannot.